# Detect ID of each form submitted

Tags: php, jquery, submit, form-submit

I try modify plugin of cms and have problem with forms

Actually i have system which generate polls for send votes and all forms are as this :

```
<div class="sp-poll" id="poll-<?php echo $pollid; ?>">
    <p class="sp-question">
        <?php echo $question; ?>
    </p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $postFile; ?>" id="spe_form-<?php echo $pollid; ?>"></form>
</div>
```

**The javascript process:**

```
jQuery(function () {

    var $ = jQuery; // Because `$` is easier than using `jQuery`
    $('.sp-poll form').submit(formProcess); // Access formProcess() when the poll is submitted

    /**
     * Form Process
     * Process through the form 
     * 
     * @param object e
     */
    function formProcess(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var poll = $('input[name=poll]').val(),
            answer = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val(),
            div = $(this).parent(),
            action = $(this).attr('action');

        $(this).slideUp('slow', function () {
            updatePoll(action, poll, answer);
        });
    }
});
```

The problem it´s each form have different ID , and the processor only detect the first id , for example if i have 5 forms with differents IDs all time detect only one ID of one form but no the others when launch the process form , i try use :

```
jQuery(".sp-poll form").attr(id);
```

But always detect the same number and no detect each ID in each form

PS : I need the send the form ID attribute since the form repeats itself each and every time I create a poll on the page. I want to be able to detect data for each different form using their ID to sort them out.

Comment: You can make a hidden input named form-id, and set the id value there. But I don't see why you process a form with JavaScript? You can post it to another php page, or do it with AJAX.

Comment: Yes the problem it´s thhe process form it´s in jquery as i put in the example of code and detect the form by .sp-poll form but no send the id and by this always process the same form and no the others forms , i need send this id or extract for process form id

Answer (score 1):

When using HTML forms, only information stored in FORM FIELDS or the URL are sent back to the server. Element IDs have nothing to do with forms at all - they're for UI manipulation.

If you want to pass the form ID back to the server, use a hidden field.

Comment: I have hidden field but the problem it´s i have many forms and processor only detect the first form no the other if i send form but processor by ajax no detect the id of form always send the same form and no the others i need send the id of form but processor use class and add form no id of form

Comment: Read this. It is a better way to extract your form data than doing the way you have it in your code. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: the problem it´s the plugin have many forms with the same class but different id , when launch process and many forms in the same page , the submit by ajax launch the class form detect and no detect the real id , in all forms detect the same $('.sp-poll form').submit(formProcess); , but id it´s different and no process the right form